# Переадресация в index без возможности замены переменной через GET-запрос

Tags: .htaccess, mod_rewrite, php

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

`example.ru/somefolder/index.php?somegetvar=somevalue`

Ожидаемый результат:
q (или любая другая переменная) получает значение всего пути.
Кроме того, записываются все переменные, которые получили через GET.
То есть:

```
[QUERY_STRING] => q=somefolder&somegetvar=somevalue
```

Что на самом деле:

```
[QUERY_STRING] => q=index.php&q=somefolder/index.php&somegetvar=somevalue
```

А если ушлый пользователь введет свою переменную q в запросе, то вообще кошмар:

```
[QUERY_STRING] => q=index.php&q=somefolder/index.php&q=somevalue
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Итак, правильный, но не факт, что оптимальный ответ:
С первой частью:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Со второй частью:

Способ первый:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?7694f4a66316e53c8cdd9d9954bd611d=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Это костыль, но предохранит от СЛУЧАЙНЫХ замен. Если доброумышленник догадается до названия переменной, будет нехорошо.

Способ второй:

```
$qs = explode('&',$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);
$getVars = array();
foreach($qs as $key=>$varvalue){
    list($var,$value) = explode('=',$varvalue);
    if(!isset($getVars[$var])){
        $getVars[$var] = $value;// Вначале всегда идут наши переменные, просто потому что mod_rewrite срабатывает раньше.
    }
}
$newQueryString = http_build_query($getVars);
```

Все. Осталось редиректнуть(хоть бы даже header-ом) и аварийно завершить скрипт. Теперь даже если кто-то допишет свои параметры, они просто исчезнут.